# Shell Progress Dialogs for a non-existent operation?

Tags: file-transfer, copy

I have just made the switch over from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and noticed that while copying files that the Shell Progress Dialogs seemed a bit long winded (taking much longer than Win7). That is to say, the animation often takes longer than the actual process does.

While copying smaller files (files around 100kb) the Shell Progress Dialog event window still takes about 0.8 seconds, despite that the operation is pretty much instant. Even copying a file that is 1 byte takes the same amount of time in the progress bar as a 1MB file. This leads me to believe that the copying progress bar is actually fake when it comes to smaller file sizes and is just there for eye candy.

[image]

Considering that my machine has 24 gigs of RAM, a GTX950 Nvidia GPU, and all very fast SSD and NVME drives (the copying taking place is always on the same drive), I thought this was odd and tried something else; I decided to press 'skip' instead of 'replace' when trying to replace a file and I noticed the progress bar animation was still happening, despite that I didn't actually perform any operation!

So my questions are:

1. Why is there Shell Progress Dialogs event for a non-existent operation?
2. Is there a way to speed up or edit the animation so that it actually reflects the amount of time an operation takes?
3. Why would Windows 10 devs make something so painfully slow for such small operations? (I mean, do I really need to watch this progress bar to feel like something is happening for such small operations)? These seconds add up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[When Slower UX is Better UX](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2017/09/when-slower-ux-is-better-ux/) (tl;dr: users don't trust that something worked if it happens too fast)

[Slow UI: Pace Interaction to Increase Understanding](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/slow-ui/) (tl;dr: *"Overly fast interfaces are error prone and encourage users to rush through websites and other systems"* - quote from summary)

> Is there a way to speed up or edit the animation so that it actually reflects the amount of time an operation takes?

Use alternative copier like [TeraCopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy). But benchmark it first: for me TeraCopy almost never faster than Windows 7 and sometimes significantly slower when I tested it a few years back.

Comment: EDIT - terra copy has system integration.. VERY fast animations for slow files.Thank you . WIll award bounty when i can.

Answer (score 1):

The file progress dialog in Windows has always been an unreliable tool.
Its reason for existence is only eye-candy, and its estimations are mostly
ridiculously wrong.

If you don't wish to use an alternate file copier,
this dialog can be disabled for speeding up all copy/move operations:

- Run from the Start menu
  "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows"
- Disable the option of
  "Animate controls and elements inside windows"
- Click OK or Apply

[image]

Comment: tried this before posting. DOesnt work windows 10 1909

Comment: Tried this before posting. Works for me on windows 10 1909. Perhaps you need to re-login.